# Preview pages error caused by invalid argument in Page.Resources

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, arguments, objectdataprovider

My xaml page includes some resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <cnv:FormattingConverter x:Key="formatter" />
    <!-- create an instance of our DataProvider class -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ObjOne" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ObjOneDataProvider}"/>
    <!-- define the method which is invoked to obtain our data -->
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ObjTwo" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ObjOne}" sMethodName="GetAllData"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

But when I try to open the page in visual studio in preview mode I get the following error:

> Error 57  Invalid argument

and the error is cause by the instruction:
ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ObjOne}"

Someone know why it occurs?

NOTE: I found that error is caused by the assign of propriety MethodName and not by the ObjectInstance="{StaticResource ObjOne}"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind to a method follow the documentation: [How to: Bind to a Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824.aspx)

```
<Page.Resources>
    <cnv:FormattingConverter x:Key="formatter" />

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ObjOne" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ObjOneDataProvider}" MethodName="GetAllData" />
</Page.Resources>
```